# Max (date) # - Min(Date) # to get the weight difference - Excel Formula

Tags: excel, date, max, formula, min

I have different entries for the weight over different periods of time and wanted to see the weight difference from the max point in time to the min point in time based on a specific ID.

```
ID      Date     Weight   Difference
12345   1/1/22    100         -10
12345   2/1/22     95         -10
12345   3/1/22     90         -10
44440   1/1/22     90          10
44440   2/1/22     95          10
44440   3/1/22    100          10
18258   2/1/22    105         -1
18258   3/1/22    104         -1
23584   3/1/22    110          0
```

So far, I have used the following formula: =MAX(IF(A:A=A2,U:U))-MIN(IF(A:A=A2,U:U))

A is the ID, U is the Weight

The formula is not taking the max date into account but the max weight and subtracting that from the min weight, instead of taking the weight from the max date and the weight from the min date.

Comment: If there is only one weight per ID per day you could use MAXIFS to include the date as selection criteria. To calculate the dates you could use your mentioned formulas accordingly.

Comment: thank you for that tip. In searching for the maxifs examples, the date has to be set equal to a specific cell ("start date") but I need it to review all the dates, select the max date with the weight - shouldnt be the max weight. So like for id 12345 - it should go to the max date and calculate using the weight 90. Right now the formula is using 100 to calculate.

Comment: Yes, you could try your formula to identify the min and max dates per ID (instead of the weight) and use these (nested) in the MAXIFS as the reference dates instead of the specific cells with a date

Comment: gasp - so much neat tips. Okay, so I was able to do the following thanks to you: =MAXIFS(U:U,C:C,C2,G:G,MAX(IF(C:C=C2,G:G)))-MINIFS(U:U,C:C,C2,G:G,MIN(IF(C:C=C2,G:G))) ; where the U is the weight, C is the ID, G is the date!  so cool! Thank you very much anon

Comment: Well done. btw, if there is only one weight value per ID per day, MAXIFS and MINIFS are interchangeable with the same result (as long as the date references are correct)

Comment: what do you mean by interchangeable? Like changes the position of the maxifs and minifs?